# Add a check for php to see if data from database is stored as JSON in localStorge

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, local-storage

I'm trying to figure out a way to make php check if data from my database is stored into the clients localStorage. I know that we don't get any data sent to php in a header like it does with a cookie. But I hope there is a way to do this, I think it would make sense from a performance point of view on the server.

I'm basicly trying to accomplish this:

1) php connects to db.

2) php echo out content from my query and decode it to JSON

3) The JSON is stored into the clients localStorage.

***And this is where I'm trying to figure out a way to check.***

4) On page refresh, php checks if (maybe with some bool set to true). item from localStorage is added. If true, don't run db connection and query.

5) data from JSON is used to display my items for the client instead.

Anyone tried this before and maybe can give me some hints / documentation to solve this.

Comment: 1) localStorage exists in the **Browser** 2) PHP runs on the **Server** and never on the Browser. So either I am not understanding your question, or you are not understanding how things work

Comment: That is how it works :) I'm just trying to figure out a way to not make a server request, but use localStorage instead, if the user comes back or refreshes his/hers page. I don't know if it is possible. But that is why I asked here :)

Comment: Well you will have to get you js to check localStorage before making another call to the PHP. So you might want to add a `age` concept to the data you store in localStorage. So if data there is older than `X` go to the server otherwise use data from localStorage

Comment: Okay, I will try that. So I kinda have to make my JS control if I run php on my page?